# Attendance record from bio-metric device

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

Here is my data

```
|Id     |EmpCode    |CheckInCheckOutDate        |WorkDate                   |InOutMode  
|247    |51         |2017-02-13 20:08:52.000    |2017-02-13 20:08:52.000    |0          
|392    |51         |2017-02-13 22:38:51.000    |2017-02-13 22:38:51.000    |1          
|405    |51         |2017-02-13 22:59:18.000    |2017-02-13 22:59:18.000    |0          
|415    |51         |2017-02-13 23:18:17.000    |2017-02-13 23:18:17.000    |1          
|423    |51         |2017-02-13 23:33:44.000    |2017-02-13 23:33:44.000    |0          
|456    |51         |2017-02-14 01:30:15.000    |2017-02-13 01:30:15.000    |1          
|463    |51         |2017-02-14 02:52:02.000    |2017-02-13 02:52:02.000    |0          
|483    |51         |2017-02-14 05:11:54.000    |2017-02-13 05:11:54.000    |1          
|1034   |51         |2017-02-14 20:09:23.000    |2017-02-14 20:09:23.000    |0          
|1172   |51         |2017-02-14 21:59:23.000    |2017-02-14 21:59:23.000    |1          
|1217   |51         |2017-02-14 22:30:28.000    |2017-02-14 22:30:28.000    |0          
|1238   |51         |2017-02-14 22:49:51.000    |2017-02-14 22:49:51.000    |1          
|1257   |51         |2017-02-14 23:19:10.000    |2017-02-14 23:19:10.000    |0          
|1315   |51         |2017-02-15 05:04:16.000    |2017-02-14 05:04:16.000    |1          
|1323   |51         |2017-02-15 05:05:17.000    |2017-02-14 05:05:17.000    |0          
|1329   |51         |2017-02-15 05:08:17.000    |2017-02-14 05:08:17.000    |1
|1330   |51         |2017-02-15 05:08:18.000    |2017-02-14 05:08:18.000    |1
```

I have used this code:

```
SELECT EmpCode,
        CAST(I.CheckInCheckOutDate AS DATE) AS [Date],
        CAST(I.WorkDate AS DATE) AS WorkDate,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.WorkDate, 108) AS CheckIn,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), O.WorkDate, 108) AS CheckOut,
       CAST(DATEDIFF(second,I.WorkDate,O.WorkDate)/3600.0 AS DECIMAL(18,9)) [TotalHours]
FROM tblAttendance I
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 WorkDate,inOutMode FROM tblAttendance t
                WHERE t.EmpCode = I.EmpCode AND t.WorkDate > I.WorkDate
                ORDER BY t.WorkDate
            ) O

WHERE I.inOutMode = 0
AND O.inOutMode = 1 and I.empCode=51
```

The result of code is:

```
|EmpCode|Date|      |WorkDate   |CheckIn    |CheckOut   |TotalHours
|51     |2017-02-13 |2017-02-13 |20:08:52   |22:38:51   |2.499722000
|51     |2017-02-13 |2017-02-13 |22:59:18   |23:18:17   |0.316388000
|51     |2017-02-13 |2017-02-13 |23:33:44   |05:04:16   |5.508888000
|51     |2017-02-14 |2017-02-13 |02:52:02   |05:11:54   |2.331111000
|51     |2017-02-14 |2017-02-14 |20:09:23   |21:59:23   |1.833333000
|51     |2017-02-14 |2017-02-14 |22:30:28   |22:49:51   |0.323055000
|51     |2017-02-15 |2017-02-14 |05:05:17   |05:08:17   |0.050000000
```

Whenever I am adding TotalHours hours Group By WorkDate, it is giving incorrect answer.

Comment: Man people around here sure like hit to that close button. It seems obvious to me that the OP has put effort into this (their first) question. We need to help the OP improve the question instead of just voting to close it.

Comment: `Whenever I am adding TotalHours hours Group By WorkDate, it is giving incorrect answer.` this doesn't help.please add your expected result and actual result

Comment: also look here to improve the question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is to add an explicit sum:
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WorkDate, inOutMode, SUM (TotalHours) FROM tblAttendance t

WHERE t.EmpCode = I.EmpCode AND t.WorkDate > I.WorkDate
GROUP BY WorkDate, inOutMode

ORDER BY t.WorkDate
```

(untested, sorry if this doesn't help - I know very limited SQL :P)

Comment: At the very least your SUM needs to be a column in the query. As posted it is invalid syntax because the SUM is just floating in nowhere land.

Comment: @SeanLange expected it wouldn't work, but you made a comment that made me at least try to help.