# Bio-Metric device record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

Hi i have get data from bio-metric device like :-

```
|Id     |EmpCode    | WorkDate                   |InOutMode  
|247    |51         | 2017-02-13 20:08:52.000    |0          
|392    |51         | 2017-02-13 22:38:51.000    |1          
|405    |51         | 2017-02-13 22:59:18.000    |0          
|415    |51         | 2017-02-13 23:18:17.000    |1          
|423    |51         | 2017-02-13 23:33:44.000    |0          
|456    |51         | 2017-02-13 01:30:15.000    |1          
|463    |51         | 2017-02-13 02:52:02.000    |0          
|483    |51         | 2017-02-13 05:11:54.000    |1          
|1034   |51         | 2017-02-14 20:09:23.000    |0          
|1172   |51         | 2017-02-14 21:59:23.000    |1          
|1217   |51         | 2017-02-14 22:30:28.000    |0
|1214   |51         | 2017-02-14 22:30:39.000    |0          
|1238   |51         | 2017-02-14 22:49:51.000    |1          
|1257   |51         | 2017-02-14 23:19:10.000    |0          
|1315   |51         | 2017-02-14 05:04:16.000    |1          
|1323   |51         | 2017-02-14 05:05:17.000    |0          
|1329   |51         | 2017-02-14 05:08:17.000    |1
|1330   |51         | 2017-02-14 05:08:18.000    |1
```

I want to get data from above table record like:-

```
|EmpCode   |WorkDate       |CheckIn    |CheckOut   |TotalHours
|51        |2017-02-13     |20:08:52   |22:38:51   |2.499722000
|51        |2017-02-13     |22:59:18   |23:18:17   |0.316388000
|51        |2017-02-13     |23:33:44   |01:30:15   |3.103330000
|51        |2017-02-13     |02:52:02   |05:11:54   |2.331111000
|51        |2017-02-14     |20:09:23   |21:59:23   |1.833333000
|51        |2017-02-14     |22:30:28   |22:49:51   |0.323055000
|51        |2017-02-14     |23:19:10   |05:04:16   |5.323055000
|51        |2017-02-14     |05:05:17   |05:08:18   |0.050000000
```

PS: The duplicate IN or OUT is ignored.13th,14th,17th and 18th lines in the raw data. 2. Minutes are in decimal point to the hour in the hours calculation.

I need help of the Sql-Server query to use to get these results.

My current code is not help me and also leave some rows and get wrong result and total of hours thanks :)

Note:- When my query excute missing two rows :-

```
|456    |51         | 2017-02-13 01:30:15.000    |1          
|463    |51         | 2017-02-13 02:52:02.000    |0
```

Comment: Well this sure looks familiar...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253727/attendance-record-from-bio-metric-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attendance record from bio-metric device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253727/attendance-record-from-bio-metric-device)

Comment: why did you post the second identical question during 6 hours period? Wait for the correct answer to your original question.

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question with in 6 hours :( no one reply currently so sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `0` in In and `1` is Out.

I included an `Overnight` column to return `1` when `CheckOut` is on the next day. You can comment it out if you do not need it.

using `cross apply()`

rextester: http://rextester.com/ENFRC28977

```
with cte as (
  select 
      Id
    , EmpCode
    , WorkDate
    , InOutMode
    , Lag_InOutMode = Lag(InOutMode) over (order by EmpCode, WorkDate)
  from t
)
select 
    i.EmpCode
  , WorkDate = convert(varchar(10),convert(date,i.WorkDate))
  , Overnight = case when datediff(day,i.WorkDate,o.WorkDate)>0 then 1 else 0 end
  , CheckIn  = convert(time,i.WorkDate)
  , CheckOut = convert(time,o.WorkDate)
  , TotalHours = datediff(second,i.WorkDate,o.WorkDate)/3600.0
from cte i 
cross apply (
    select top 1 WorkDate
    from cte o
    where o.EmpCode = i.EmpCode
      and o.InOutMode = 1
      and o.Lag_InOutMode != 1
      and o.WorkDate > i.WorkDate
    order by o.WorkDate asc
    ) as o
where i.InOutMode = 0 
  and i.Lag_InOutMode != 0
order by i.WorkDate
```

returns:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+
| EmpCode |  WorkDate  | Overnight | CheckIn  | CheckOut | TotalHours |
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+
|      51 | 2017-02-13 |         0 | 02:52:02 | 05:11:54 | 2,331111   |
|      51 | 2017-02-13 |         0 | 20:08:52 | 22:38:51 | 2,499722   |
|      51 | 2017-02-13 |         0 | 22:59:18 | 23:18:17 | 0,316388   |
|      51 | 2017-02-13 |         1 | 23:33:44 | 05:04:16 | 5,508888   |
|      51 | 2017-02-14 |         0 | 05:05:17 | 05:08:17 | 0,050000   |
|      51 | 2017-02-14 |         0 | 20:09:23 | 21:59:23 | 1,833333   |
|      51 | 2017-02-14 |         0 | 22:30:28 | 22:49:51 | 0,323055   |
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

I do not see a `0` `InOutMode` prior to for `'2017-02-13 01:30:15'`, so my results do not contain a row for:

```
|51        |2017-02-13     |23:33:44   |01:30:15   |3.103330000
```

Comment: Thanks but missing some rows from above query :(

|456    |51         | 2017-02-13 01:30:15.000    |1          
|463    |51         | 2017-02-13 02:52:02.000    |0

Comment: @GoutamSingh as I said at the bottom of my answer, there is no `CheckIn` prior to the `CheckOut` of `2017-02-13 01:30:15`. So there won't be a row with that. Also, if you look at my results, you'll notice the first row is for `CheckIn` of `2017-02-13 02:52:02.000`, so it is clearly not missing.  Why don't you look at your example data and expected results again? It looks like you just mash it up every time you ask a new question. e.g. You re-use ids with different workdates across questions and change workdates across questions. This is obviously not a valid sample of what you are working from

Comment: @Sqlzip thanks :) yeah actually there are fault in data ,and I solved thanks for support :)

Comment: @GoutamSingh you should consider accepting this answer since it clearly led to a solution